# Mix Real and Complex{Real} in a function f(a::T, x::T) where T <: Union{Real, Complex{Real}}

Tags: types, julia, complex-numbers

I have a function like this:

```
function f(
        a::T,
        x::T
    )::T where {R<:Real, T<:Union{R,Complex{R}}}
    return g(R(2), a, 1, x)
end
```

I would like to allow the user to enter `f(a,x)` with `a` `Real` and `x` `Complex{Real}`, by identifying the `Real` `a` to a complex number with `im = 0`.

This is not possible with this implementation. If the user does `f(2.0, 1.0+1.0im)` then an error is returned (no method). So the user has to do `f(2.0+0im, 1.0+1.0im)`.

What should I do in order that `f(2.0, 1.0+1.0im)` would be possible ?

---

## EDIT

I have not tried, but maybe I could do

```
function f(
        a::Union{R,Complex{R}},
        x::Union{R,Complex{R}}
    )::??? where {R<:Real}
    return g(R(2), a, 1, x)
end
```

But then what should I put in place of `???` ?

Comment: Is it necessary to restrict the type of output from the function, rather than just let the compiler figure it out from the result of the `g` method?

Comment: This seems really complicated. Do you really need these restrictions? For example, does the type of the real value have to match the type parameter of the complex value? That is, do you need to reject `f(1, 1.0 + 2.0im)`?

Comment: Could `f(a::Number, x::Number) = g(oftype(a, 2), a, oftype(x, 1), x)` be acceptable?

Comment: I see now that you require the first input to `g` to be real, so then: `f(a::Number, x::Number) = g(oftype(real(a), 2), a, oftype(x, 1), x)`, or some variation. But I am concerned that you are going overboard on the types. Most well-designed Julia code has very few type annotations (or none!), _except_ where you need to manage different behaviours for different input types.

Comment: Thank you @DNF. I will think about your comments. I'm rather new to Julia and I'm trying type annotations to understand how they work. That's true they are not necessary (except for better readibility, perhaps). I very like Haskell and we always do type annotations in Haskell, and I like that, but that does not work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

**Original Answer:**

What I believe you are looking for is the following,

```
function f(a::T, x::R) where {T<:Real,R<:Complex{T}}
    g(R(2), a, one(T), x)
end
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to be able to accept both `Real` and `Complex`, the most straightforward approach would be to simply rely on the fact that the subtypes of `Number` are `Real` & `Complex`.

```
function f(a::T, x::R) where {T<:Number, R<:Number}
    g(R(2), a, one(T), x)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think so. I want `f(a,x)` to be possible for `a` real or complex and `x` real or complex. This means for possibilities : `f(real,real)`, `f(real,complex)`, `f(complex,real)`, `f(complex, complex)`.

Comment: If I understand what you are looking for, I believe the explanation of why it doesn't work as you intended has to due with https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/types/#Diagonal-types-1 .  Even though you are dispatching on for example `a::T where T<:Union{Real,Complex}`, that doesn't mean `x::T` can follow the same `Union{Real,Complex}` as `a::T`.  It means that `a` and `x` must be the same type for dispatch.

Comment: Thanks. That seems better. My real code is much more complicated than that so I cannot really test like that (my question is not very well-posed). However there's one problem: when I do `R(2)`, the type `R` must be `Real`. So `f(real, complex)` would fail here. What do you think of the code in my Edit ? I give you +1 anyway for the help. The link about the "diagonal types" is interesting.

Comment: `2one(real(a))` for example would return `2one(real(3+2im)) == 2` for an `Int` or `2one(real(3.0+2.0im)) == 2.0` for a `Float64` and would be type stable and constant propagated.

Comment: `f(a::Union{R,Complex{R}}, x::Union{R,Complex{R}}) where R<:Real` would give the Real type, provided that both `a` and `x` are either of type `R` or `Complex{R}`.